# Integrate custom login form with joomla login module

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla site but i want to integrate custom login page. How can i pass values from custom login form to joomla login module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Joomla! Module or Component standard output can be overridden easily

The standard output from any Joomla! Module or Component can be overridden by adding code to the `html` directory of your template.

See documentation: [How to override the output from the Joomla! Core Extensions](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core?language=English)

**In your case:** If you want to override output of the login Page, which is actually output of Joomla! core com_users component's login view's default(default.php) layout.

To override it, simply follow the below steps:

**Step 1**: Locate the layout in login view directory: 
`<joomla_application_root>/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default.php`

**Step 2**: Copy it to your template's `html` directory as: 
`<joomla_application_root>/templates/<your_template>/html/com_users/login/default.php`

**Step 3**: Open `<joomla_application_root>/templates/<your_template>/html/com_users/login/default.php` in any of your favorite editor.

**Step 4**: You would find default Joomla! login page form elements there. Now you can override this layout as per your needs.

Similarly any component or module layout can also be easily modified using the same approach. In addition to that Joomla! provides plugins way to add-on or extends  its Core Extensions. For example, You can create a user type plugin to add your required fields (like security questions) to the default Joomla! registration. See: [Creating a profile(user) plugin in Joomla!](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin)

Comment: I believe that the op is asking about adding additional form fields and not overriding the styling.

Comment: His Question is a bit confusing better say doesn't have sufficient details. I think he is asking one of the three things: 1) Just Add some More Fields 2) Add new Fields and Overriding the layout 3) He Neither want to ask for the override nor for the new fields since his statement 'pass values from custom login form to joomla login module' doesn't make much sense, he could have just asked for a JavaScript solution to pass and submit the values(that is username, email, password etc) from Joomla Login form (or a customized one) to Core Joomla Login Module might be somewhere placed on his webpage.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the login fields and the functions of the core component, `com_users` will need to be modified. You'll need to create a plugin that can extend the component.

In `/components/com_users/controllers/user.php` there is a `UsersControllerUser` class which extends `UsersController`. Within that class is the function `login()` which handles the fields the login form sends. Your plugin will need to extend that class to modify the `login()` function.

This link might help:
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin